# Disable automatic deployment to NuGet in AppVeyor

Tags: continuous-integration, nuget, appveyor

I want to accomplish following flow:

- All commits are built by AppVeyor and .nupkg is created with version for example `1.2.3-{build}`.
- When I decide code is stable enough, I want to manually deploy it to NuGet with version `1.2.3` (without build number suffix).
- Then I change env variable from `1.2.3` to `1.2.4` and process is repeated.

I have almost complete AppVeyor configuration, but I encountered following problem:

AppVeyor tries to deploy every build to NuGet. I want to be able to manually pick which builds I will promote to stable and push them to NuGet.

How can I make AppVeyor not deploying any build without my action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use **Environment** instead of **Inline** deployment. Difference is described [here](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/#overview)

For your scenario you can simple remove deployment from build and create new NuGet deployment **Environment** to manually call is against specific build when needed.

Comment: Now I see - I needed to remove deployment from build. What do you think is best way to "promote" continuous build to stable? PowerShell script triggering new build via API with env var indicating stable version? And then another API call to deploy this stable build to NuGet?

Comment: I suggested you Environments because I was under impression that you need manual deploy. People actually tag builds on a GitHub and have setting to deploy only tagged builds, thus deployment still goes automatically, but when needed. Or you can check-in only stable code to specific branch and have deployment only from that branch. More details how to filter by branch or tag [here](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/). Note that you cannot do deployment filtering on both tags and branches the same time.